# Can any Op-Amp be used as a voltage follower(buffer)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, unity-gain

I have a square wave, to which I have to add a buffer. The Frequency of the square wave is around 10MHz. I am new to Op-Amps, but I have read that I need a high slew rate.

Can I use any Op-Amp(with a high slew rate) as my buffer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your square wave of variable amplitude or rail-to-rail?

Comment: what do you need of that square wave? is actual amplitude relevant, or is it actually "the higher, the steeper, the better"?

Comment: The Square wave is of fixed amplitude. It is generated by a rpm sensor, its frequency is important.

Comment: What is the source impedance?  Mainly, op amps connected as buffers lower the source impedance, but you might want voltage gain as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A voltage follower is a unity-gain amplifier, and not all op-amps are stable in unity gain configuration.

You need to specifically choose an op-amp that is "unity-gain stable".

Of course you also need to find an op-amp with the required slew rate; able to produce the output current needed by your load; able to work with the power supplies available; able to produce the required voltage swing when using those power supply voltages; etc.

Comment: Can you use an Emitter Follower?

Comment: Is there anything else than an op-amp that can be used here?

Comment: @UdayanJoshi, If you're just interested in buffering a square wave and preserving its frequency (but not saving any information about its amplitude), then you can use a digital buffer. Which one and how to connect it depends on the details of the source and the square wave signal.